# Sql Server 2005 Check Constraint not being applied in execution when using variables

Tags: sql-server

Here is some SQL sample code:

```
--Create 2 Sales tables with constraints based on the saledate
create table Sales1(SaleDate datetime, Amount money)
ALTER TABLE dbo.Sales1 ADD CONSTRAINT
    CK_Sales1 CHECK (([SaleDate]>='01 May 2010'))
GO
create table Sales2(SaleDate datetime, Amount money)
ALTER TABLE dbo.Sales2 ADD CONSTRAINT
    CK_Sales2 CHECK (([SaleDate]<'01 May 2010'))
GO

--Insert some data into Sales1
insert into Sales1 (SaleDate, Amount)
values ('02 May 2010', 50)
insert into Sales1 (SaleDate, Amount)
values ('03 May 2010', 60)
GO

--Insert some data into Sales2
insert into Sales2 (SaleDate, Amount)
values ('30 Mar 2010', 10)
insert into Sales2 (SaleDate, Amount)
values ('31 Mar 2010', 20)
GO

--Create a view that combines these 2 tables
create VIEW [dbo].[Sales]
AS
    SELECT SaleDate, Amount FROM Sales1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SaleDate, Amount FROM Sales2
GO

--Get the results
--Query 1
select * from Sales where SaleDate < '31 Mar 2010' -- if you look at the execution plan this query only looks at Sales2 (Which is good)

--Query 2
DECLARE @SaleDate datetime
SET @SaleDate = '31 Mar 2010'
select * from Sales where SaleDate < @SaleDate -- if you look at the execution plan this query looks at Sales1 and Sales2 (Which is NOT good)
```

Looking at the execution plan you will see that the two queries are differnt. For Query 1 the only table that is accessed is Sales1 (which is good). For Query 2 both tables are accessed (Which is bad). Why are these execution plans different, and how do i get Query 2 to only access the relevant table when variables are used?

I have tried to add indexes for the SaleDate column and that does not seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

A query plan is cached for reuse, so it is created for the general case.  The cached plan has to be valid for all possible values of `@SalesDate`.  That means the query plan must look in both views.

You can avoid that by running dynamic sql:

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = 'select * from Sales where SaleDate < ' + @SaleDate
exec (@sql)
```

There is an option to optimize a query for a specific value of a variable, like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Sales 
WHERE SaleDate < ' + @SaleDate
OPTION ( OPTIMIZE FOR (@SalesDate = '2010-01-01') )
```

But SQL Server would still look at both tables, because it has to return the correct results for `2009-01-01` even if it's trying to optimize for `2010-01-01`.

Answer (score 0):

This is as expected. The plan is now reusable with any value in the variable.

With a literal value, it doesn't bother with resuability because the plan changes if the literal changes.

Now, I had an excellent link describing this behaviour.. the key word being *had*...

Edit:

- [Conor's article](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/CONOR/post/Contradictions-within-Contradictions.aspx) that is related about parameterisation.
- SO: [TSQL Constants… Use Variable or Literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459173/tsql-constants-use-variable-or-literal)